# jQuery form trigger action after HTML submit

Tags: jquery, html, web.py, jquery-events

I am trying to display a loading gif while a file is uploaded to a server. Using a webpy backend, I am able to sucessfully upload the file etc. but am having problems getting my jQuery to recognize that the button was clicked.

```
<html>

<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery.js"></script>

</head>

<div id="form_wrapper">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function)(){
    jQuery('#sub').click(function(){
        jQuery('#gifdiv').show();
        jQuery('#form').hide();
    });
});
    </script>

<div id="gifdiv" style="display: none">

    <img src="/static/some.gif" style="display: auto;" id="loading">

</div>

<div id="form" style:"display: auto">
    <form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform">

        <input type="file" name="file">
        <br>
        <input class="button" type="submit" id="sub">

    </form>

</div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: The upload is with Ajax or classic submit form?

Comment: pretty obvious is the classic submit

Comment: its using the classic html submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<div id="gifdiv">
    <img src="http://wallpoper.com/images/00/41/28/09/loading_00412809.jpg" style="display: auto;" id="loading">
</div>

<div id="form" style:"display: auto">
    <form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform">

        <input type="file" name="file">
        <br>
        <input class="button" type="submit" id="sub">

    </form>

</div>
```

css:

```
#gifdiv{
  display: none; 
  width:100px; 
  height:100px; 
  background-color: red;
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#sub').click(function(evt){
    $('#gifdiv').show();
    $('#form').hide();


    //These 2 lines are there to stop the form from submitting.
    //for debugging only, so that you can see the hide/show
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

codepen link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPOYmw

Edit:  Just some after thought.. You understand that this approach you are taking maybe affected by extremely small file sizes right? That is if the file gets uploaded too quickly. you will not see the image.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do :

**HTML:**

```
 <form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform">

        <input type="file" name="file">
        <br>
        <button class="button" id="sub">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function)(){
    jQuery('#sub').click(function(){
        jQuery('#gifdiv').show();
        jQuery('#myForm').submit();
        jQuery('#form').hide();
    });
});
```